# onItemSelectedListner implement abstract method

Tags: java, android, class

I successfully reconciled the below coding with a little help from this forum, however when I run the Android emulator it states that I need to change public class Main3Activity to abstract or implement abstract method for onItemSelectedListner. If the Main3Activity gets changed to abstract it cannot be instantiated, therefore assuming I need to make change somewhere in the onItemSelectedListner but cannot work out what. Any assistance is appreciated.

```
public class Main3Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);
final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
final Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
final TextView textView8=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);

spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        if (spinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Selection 1")
                && spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Option 2"))
        {
            textView8.setText("3");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
});

}
```

Comment: You've declared that `MainActivity` implements the `OnItemSelectedListener` interface, but you've not implemented the interface methods in it. You don't seem to be using `MainActivity` as an `OnItemSelectedListener`, though, so you could just remove `implements OnItemSelectedListener`.

Comment: Thanks @MikeM. that is what it was. I have removed and it now works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a new instance of OnItemSelectedListener inside of the setOnItemSelectedListener() method, you don't need to have your MainActivity implement the interface (since you're already handling it).

You can remove *implements OnItemSelectedListener* and you should be good to go. Your class declaration would then look like this:

```
public class Main3Activity extends AppCompatActivity
```

If you wanted to have the listener as part of your Activity instead, you need to implement the methods required by the interface inside of your Activity. For example:

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    // TODO: Do something here
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    // TODO: Do something here
}
```

and then set the listener:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

For more information about interfaces in Java, here is some good reading: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_interfaces.htm

Comment: Thanks for the additional information Eric, greatly appreciated.